# How to Store Strings in a Vector in Alphabetical Order in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to store an array of strings in to a two dim vector in the following order..

```
    String Starts with 'A' or 'a' --> vector[0][]
    String Starts with 'B' or 'b' --> vector[1][]
                      .
                      .
    String Starts with 'Z' or 'z' --> vector[25][]

 <------------------- Code---------------------------->

string alphaU = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ";
string alphaL = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyz";
string alphsaL ="1234567890123456789012345";
//26 buckets
vector<string> V[26];



//insert element into bucket according to the first alphabet 
for (int h = 0; h < 26; h++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i].at(0) == alphaU.at(h) || arr[i].at(0) == alphaL.at(h))
        {
            V[h].push_back(arr[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

But I am getting some access violation error. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You mention a 2D vector but your code only has a 1D vector. which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the fact that characters can be casted into integer using ASCII codes.
for example : `'A' = 65`.
So you can use this to get the index value where the element needs to be inserted.To run the following code you must include `<cctype>` header for toupper function.

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
   char front = arr[i].at(0);
   /* Make Sure that you calculate index by first converting it to upper case*/
   int index = (int)(std::toupper(front) - 'A');
   v[index].push_back(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: _Thanks_ Rishab bhai

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( int h = 0 ; h<j ; h++ )                // ordering using two for loops
{

    for(int l=0; l<j; l++)

    {

         if(uniq[l]>uniq[l+1])                //checking if the counter value is bigger or smaller

        {

            temp = counter[l];

            counter[l] = counter[l+1];              //ordering of both string and int

            counter[l+1] = temp;

            temp_1= uniq[l];

            uniq[l] = uniq[l+1];

            uniq[l+1] = temp_1;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the size of `string arr[]` is `n`;

```
vector<string> data(26);

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int idx1 = arr[i][0] - 65;
    int idx2 = arr[i][0] - 97;
    if( idx1 >= 0 && idx1 < 26 )
        data[idx1].push_back(arr[i]);
    else if (idx2 >= 0 && idx2 < 26)
        data[idx1].push_back(arr[i]);
    else {
        // I don't know what do you want to do in case of string not starting with alphabets.
    }
}
```